# How to start a tower.js project?

Tags: node.js, towerjs

I want to start a new project using tower.js, I did some research and I think it's very cool, but after I installed it and tried to generate a new project using `tower new app` I got this: `Cookbook [app] not found.` I know that tower changed the way the generators work and now are built from cookbooks, but I'm not really an expert on this kind of stuff, so I would like to get some recommendations about how to generate a new project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in another answer, Github is the best place to resolve issues and ask questions. We're not on the IRC either.

We've been currently putting a lot of effort into the client-side of things. Thus, the cookbooks aren't finished (the same goes for the `new` cookbook). We'll be bringing those pieces to standard very soon.